# url-open: response code 3 - sftp datapower

Tags: sftp, ibm-datapower

I'm using DataPower to connect with SFTP server and write XML file contains content of request to server as the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="targetUrl" select="'sftp://username:password@host:22/Test.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="response">
   <dp:url-open target="{$targetUrl}" response="responsecode"><xsl:copy-of select="current()"/></dp:url-open>
</xsl:variable>
```

I got following error:

```
 url-open: response code 3
url-open: Remote error on url 'sftp://host:22/Test.xml'
```

I search on this error, I find the following [URL](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21377318). Error Code 3 is meaning `Resource not found (user may retry with different opener)`.

**Details:**
If I used local SFTP server, the above code is working fine, Also If I used FileZilla to connect with remote SFTP server, it's working fine ?

So, It's weird the issue on my code .. or on Remote SFTP Server !!

What's the meaning of the above error .. how can I fix this error ??

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember at some previous job that I hit this issue, and it turned out that for some SFTP servers, coming in via an `sftp` URL required you to give a full path even if that user has a default directory.  Try some variation of:

```
sftp://username:password@host:22/full/path/to/file/Test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<xsl:variable name="targetUrl" select="'sftp://username:password@host:22/~/Test.xml'"/>
```